# iOS dismiss all keyboard and modal controls

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I am making a network based application and I've stumbled across a little dilema. My app connects to the server and the application uses the keyboard and displays a modal view when certain buttons are pressed. This is all fine and working as I want it to. My issue is when the server loses connection whether for maintenance or we lose connection the app goes back to the login screen, but the keyboard or modal views don't get dismissed. Do I have to keep track of these to dismiss them or is there some global command that I could send to dismiss everything.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of different ways to dismiss the keyboard: 
One of these should work:

```
[myEditField resignFirstResponder];
[myEditField endEditing];
[parentView endEditing];
```

There is no "global" way to dismiss all open modal views. You will need to specifically dismiss any modal views you've opened using:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
// This can be called either from within the modal view or its parent:
```

Comment: So I have to keep track of who is being displayed and have the parent dismiss them so to speak?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. There's no "global" command that will, say, close any/all modal views. You could try using Notifications for this, however. For example, the parent fires a notification, and any views who receive it should dismiss themselves. That's another option. Look at NSNotificationCenter if you choose to go that route.

Comment: I've decided to go the Notification route. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 4):

In your view controller user:

```
[self.view endEditing: YES];
```

This will `resignFirstResponder` for all subviews of your main view. No need to keep track of which textField is first responder.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered a case where `endEditing` and `resignFirstResponder` fail. This has worked for me in those cases.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];    
[self setEditing:NO];
```

Comment: Been looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a private property to hold the current modal view and/or text field that has the focus.  Then when you lose your connection, use the value of that property (which you set on instantiation of the modal view) to dismiss the current one.